# Functional approach for a transaction processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create a transactional file by comparing 2 files (old vs new). If the key is in old file and not in new file, I have to populate an indicator ‘D’ at the end of the record and if the key is in new file and not in old file, the record should get indicator ‘A’ and if the keys are matched and there is a change in the remaining record, the record should get indicator ‘C’.
Sample data looks like this.

Old File:

```
Key Value
10000   Apple
20000   Orange
30000   Melon
40000   Berry
50000   Cherry
```

New File:

```
Key Value
10001   Pear
20002   Pineapple
30000   Melon
40000   Strawberry
50000   SweetCherry
```

Expected Result:

```
Key Value   Indicator
10000   Apple   D
20000   Orange  D
10001   Pear    A
20002   Pineapple   A
40000   Strawberry  C
50000   SweetCherry C
```

I have written the following program to achieve this.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object transaction {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("transaction")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val oldFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/root/OLDFILE.txt")
    val newFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/root/NEWFILE.txt")
    val oldMap = oldFile.map(rec => (rec.substring(0,9), rec))
    val newMap = newFile.map(rec => (rec.substring(0,9), rec))
    val tranJoin = oldMap.fullOuterJoin(newMap)
    val tranFinal = tranJoin.map(rec => {
      if (rec._2._1 == None)
        rec._2._2.mkString+" A"
      else
      if (rec._2._2 == None)
        rec._2._1.mkString+" D"
      else
      if (rec._2._1 != rec._2._2)
        rec._2._2.mkString+" C"
    }).filter(rec => rec.toString.substring(0,1) != "(")
 tranFinal.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/root/transfinal")
}
```

I would like to know if there is a more functional way to write this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better and more efficient ways to do this. Start by reading the data as a DataFrame instead of an RDD. For a CSV file, it can look like this (with header and "," as spearator but this can be changed):

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("OLDFILE")
val df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("NEWFILE")
```

Then, rename one of the `Value` column and join the data together. The `Indicator` column can be created simply by looking at the values of the two `Value` columns.

```
val df = df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("Value", "Value2"), Seq("Key"), "outer")
  .withColumn("Indicator", when($"Value".isNull, "A")
                          .when($"Value2".isNull, "D")
                          .when($"Value2" =!= $"Value", "C")
                          .otherwise("-"))
  .filter($"Indicator" =!= "-")
  .withColumn("Value", coalesce($"Value2", $"Value"))
  .drop($"Value2")
```

Here, columns that appear in both datasets and where the value doesn't change are removed. `coalesce` returns the first column in the list that is not null, so it works perfectly for our purposes of merging the two columns. The final result:

```
+-----+-----------+---------+
|  Key|      Value|Indicator|
+-----+-----------+---------+
|10000|      Apple|        D|
|10001|       Pear|        A|
|20000|     Orange|        D|
|50000|SweetCherry|        C|
|40000| Strawberry|        C|
|20002|  Pineapple|        A|
+-----+-----------+---------+
```